# jQuery find element in iframe not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to find all elements in an iframe which have some word in them, e.g. 'stack' in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow

This is my code:

```
<body>
    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow"></iframe>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var iframe = $('iframe');
        $( "iframe" ).contents().find( "stack" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
</script>
```

There is some CSS and other elements to make it full page, and the jQuery library is included.

Nevertheless, no elements are selected and are having the css applied. Can anyone point out where this is going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You can't! [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) doesn't allow you.

Comment: @Vohuman Yes I thought that would be an issue. Any way to fix such a thing? Parse the whole page to my server first?

Comment: That's an option. You can also use PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that, but it was just for some testing purposes, I think this exceeds that a bit :) Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: You are welcome! PhantomJS is easy to use :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$( "iframe:contains('stack')" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it unfortunately. Probably Same-origin policy as @Vohuman pointed out